# Setting CNAME for App-Engine Website (without a custom Domain) for Configuring a Google Cloud Storage Bucket as a Website

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, cname

I have an app-engine application deployed at gaeid.appspot.com and a the same project has GCS bucket named store.gaeid.appspot.com that I want to configure as as a website.

[GCS documentation says](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration#step2) that I need to create a CNAME record to point store.gaeid.appspot.com to c.storage.googleapis.com which I couldn't find an option in GAE to do for the GAE app (without a custom Domain).

Is there a way point store.gaeid.appspot.com to the bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not manage the DNS domain appspot.com. So you can only use your own domain with a cname properly configured as described in the documentation.

edit:

For using a bucket as a website:

- the name of the bucket need to be exactly the url of the website: `www.example.com`
- the www of example.com need to be pointed to `c.storage.googleapis.com` through domain's dns panel.

you do not have a panel of dns for the domain `appspot.com` and  Google don't provide this feature.

However, you can use the good old method of static folder in GAE with a tiny configuration in `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:

- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /static
  static_dir: www/static
```

Comment: Hi Gianni, Thanks for your response. Which documentation are you talking about? are you saying custom domain is only option?

Comment: @Ashish Yes, custom domain is the only one option for a static website in GCS, alternatively look the edited answer.

Comment: I am using the bucket to generate the HTML files at run time based on the data and then saving them on GCS. It will not work with static files as generated files will not be part of application code that are copied to all deployments.

Comment: appspot.com point to the application code. No way to point it to GCS bucket. The DNS is the key. ok?